# BlackBerry - How to detect the bluetooth headset connection event?

Tags: blackberry, audio, bluetooth, headset

I have a bluetooth headset that I paired with my blackberry storm. Whenever I turn on/off the headset, my storm displays the message that the headset is been connected or disconnected and updates the bluetooth indicator icon. I would like to detect that headset connect change event in my application. How do i capture that event change? I know that "Audiolistener" can capture the headset connect event. but I don't know whether it will do for bluetooth headset.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[BlackBerry Support Community Forums:BlackBerry Development:Java Development:AudioListener](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/AudioListener/m-p/208507):

> There is no listener that provides notifications for when a user connects or disconnects a headset.
>   Mark Sohm
>   BlackBerry Development Advisor
>   www.BlackBerryDeveloper.com

Comment: Still true with later recent Blackberry versions?  Looks like the audio is rerouted to speaker when unplugging the headset, for some situations.